# How can i add bulletin points in my products description

Tags: magento-1.9, product-view, styles

I need to add bulletin point in my products description.

Comment: You mean an ordered list? In that case you can just use the WYSIWYG editor or use HTML ```<ul><li>Text</li></ul>```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add this unicode for bullets in your description,

Bullet : "•"

```
&#8226; Product Description Point 1
&#8226; Product Description Point 2
```

Above string looks like,

• Product Description Point 1

• Product Description Point 2